# Creating linear structuring element in opencv c++

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

Doing some research, I found that in Matlab they have this function to create linear structuring elements with a certain angle:

```
strel('line',len,deg)
```

The documentations says `creates a linear structuring element that is symmetric with respect to the neighborhood center, with approximate length len and angle deg.`, which basically is a Mat like this with different sizes and angles:

[image]

I'm trying to create a similar structuring element in different angles but I couldnt find an equivalent function in Opencv for C++. Is there a way of doing that?

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The closest function OpenCV has is [`getStructuringElement`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gac342a1bb6eabf6f55c803b09268e36dc). Unfortunately, the only shapes it supports are [rectangle, cross and ellipse](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gac2db39b56866583a95a5680313c314ad).

Therefore, it is probably the easiest to create/estimate it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Paul. Would know an algorithm to rotate this line of 1s inside a matrix? I could get to print diagonals, vertical, and horizontally, but I'm cant think of a solution to rotate like 15 by 15 degrees